# Measure DDOS attack strength

Tags: denial-of-service

I have been puzzled on this theory. Assume Server B is sending DDOS attack to Server A, so is it possible for a random client A, to be able to measure the attack strength, like the client A was able to determine the strength of TCP attack @ 73GBPS (example) made by Server B to Server A, without having access to neither Server A or B. I assume it's impossible unless you're the attacker or you're the target? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Define "measure"

Comment: @Havenard updated the question :)

Comment: An observator would only be able to notice stuff like increase in latency, packet loss, and possibly turbulence in transfer speed assuming he is able to download/upload stuff from the given server, obviously nothing accurate. Not to mention all of that is also susceptible to variations in his own connection and route.

Comment: @Havenard That I agree too, you should post that as an answer by the way

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution, but I can help you understand the problem better so maybe you could find the solution.

First you need to understand that Server B can not DDOS Server A. The acronym DDOS stands for "**Distributed** denial of service".

So what does that mean?

It means "a server is given a load larger than its available capacity so that new requests can not be responded to in a timely manner.". In a DDOS attack the attacker does not need to send any kind of malicious data to the server, they can be legitimate requests.

If your site is designed to handle 500 visitors per second and an attacker has 20,000 computers under his control in a botnet he could just tell all 20,000 computers to go to the web page and just start hitting refresh and that would take down your server. You as a server owner can not tell the difference between a botnet computer hitting refresh and a real user hitting refresh. So you you can only start replying to 1 in 40 requests to your server and now the server is DDOSed

So now your question changes to "Without access to a server can I measure the load of traffic on that server". I don't know the answer to that question but I bet you will have a easier time finding the answer to that than "How do I measure the DDOS strength between two servers".